# problem automatic logout user after refreshing the page or changing the page or after a few minutes

Tags: asp.net, api, c#-4.0, web-config, forms-authentication

i use this code for login user in my api:

```
var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
    1,
    CurrentCustommer.PhoneNumber,
    DateTime.Now,
    DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(FormsAuthentication.Timeout.TotalMinutes),
    false,
    "user,user1",
    FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath
);
var encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket)
{
    HttpOnly = true,
    Secure = FormsAuthentication.RequireSSL,
    Path = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath,
    Domain = FormsAuthentication.CookieDomain
};
HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendCookie(cookie);
```

my webconfig code is:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx" protection="All" timeout="10080" slidingExpiration="true">
  </forms>
</authentication>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.2" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.2" />
<pages enableSessionState="true" validateRequest="false"></pages>
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="10080" />
```

now. user after login and after a few minutes and refresh page or change page in site, Automatically Log outed; I see cookies stored through the "document.cookie" in chrome console. this problem does not exist in local host but when used server this problem showed :/

Also, I add that I use my customized database and don't use sql membership provider asp.net.

Should I apply certain settings when I call the method API for user login? Or I need to apply other configurations?

Really I do not know how to fix this problem.

thanks all.

UPDATE:  i check authenticate user by this code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        //Page.Response.Redirect("/");
        MainContainer.Visible = false;
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), 
        "CallMyFunction", "LoginForm()", true);
    }
}
```

for more info And i now see **Page.User.ExpireDate** in watch in Page_Load, this time 30 minutes after login user.

Comment: Do you have control of the server? If so set the timeout in iis, set time-out, under ASP, Services, Session properties.

Comment: @Sgedda hi. Yes, I have access. It happens that after a few minutes the same problem persists.

Comment: And what it says, time-out setting in your iis?

Answer (score 0):

cookieless="false" can you just try using cookieless property as default or true